# How to make an onclick in a img html5 tag call a function with a parameter?

Tags: javascript

I want my img link to call a javascript function that will send a name which will be a video.mp4 name to the function sendName. At this point sendName should just display an alert.

In the end I want to call the jwplayer inside of a function that I can send in a parameter with a movie name so that it will play the particular movie. The name valley.mp4 is were the variable will be placed. If I put the jwplayer inside of a function then the player will not load on the screen.

so when I click on a movie name then it will play that movie. This is for my own use at home.

```
<li class="topfirst"><a href="#" style="width:574px;">
<img src="s/256base-open-over.png" onClick="sendName('a.mp4');">Dr. No. (1962)</a></li>
```

Other code Here:

```
jwplayer("test").setup({
  playlist: [{
    image: "0001.jpg",
    sources: [
    {file: "valley.mp4",label: "144p"}
    ]
  }]
});
```

Test function:

```
function sendName(name) {
  alert(name);
}
```

[image]

Comment: onclick, not onClick (using html5 doctype)

Answer (score 1):

You could use data attributes to store params. When the event is fired you the target from event.target and then you could use its data attributes.

```
// based on jQuery

$('img').on('click', function (event) {
  var btn = $(event.target);

  sendName(btn.data('video-name'));
});
```

You should follow similar pattern.

Comment: Can you post an example of this.